# Adding padding to bottom of scrollview in android?

Tags: android, xml, scrollview

I want to add padding to the bottom of this scrollview since the text overlaps with the ads I have at the bottom. I am fairly new to android dev. I looked at several other posts but couldnt seem to figure out my problem. Thanks!

Here is my weddingfragment.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fillViewport="false"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:scrollbars="horizontal" android:id="@+id/ScrollView">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"                      
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal">

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Formal or Black Tie"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" 
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=" • This means you should wear a Tuxedo or a dark colored suit."
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
   </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Here is my activity_main.xml which is the parent of weddingfragment.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     ads:adUnitId=""
                     ads:adSize="BANNER"
                     ads:testDevices=""
                     ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
                     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You should be able to add the scrollview and then the ads view if it's at the bottom in the top level container, no? (I don't see where you add the weddingfragment, not sure if you're adding it via code or by fragment)

See my edit of your code (I just threw in a copy of an xml fragment I have in my project): http://pastebin.com/F6DSmzns

Comment: Also you should remove your adUnitId when you post to pastebin so someone doesn't spam it or something. That could be be bad if they were to compromise your account validity.

Comment: I was adding it by code but I will try via fragment. Thanks that cleared it up for me!

Comment: @Mgamerz Thanks for catching that

Comment: If you don't need to change it out during runtime you can probably leave it as XML. If you need to change it you'll have to do it programmatically since you won't be able to get a reference to it properly. In that case... (I'll post my example code as an answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in the comments, here is an example of XML which you can use to make runtime changes of fragments and still have your adview:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

<!-- Get a reference to this fragment and use the fragment .commit() to change it. See the API guides for more info. It must be a framelayout or you can't edit it. -->
        <FrameLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/frag_wedding_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >
        </FrameLayout>

<com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     ads:adUnitId=""
                     ads:adSize="BANNER"
                     ads:testDevices=""
                     ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
                     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

    </LinearLayout>
```